# Can I install two versions of QGIS on the same computer?

Tags: qgis, installation

I thought a few weeks ago someone asked a question about running multiple versions of qgis on the same computer.  But I can't find it back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you install Qgis standalone version on your computer, it installs in a folder with release name under *C:\Program Files*. Therefore it shouldnot be a problem.

When you install the following versions, they go in the respective folders

```
QGIS 1.8.0 Release --> Quantum GIS Lisboa
QGIS 1.7.4 Release --> Quantum GIS Wroclaw
QGIS 1.5.0 Release --> Quantum GIS Tethys
```

I hope it helps you...

Answer (score 6):

You can have multiple versions of QGIS installed through OSGeo4W. 
One is called qgis, the other qgis-dev (in advanced installation).

I've been running OSGeo4W on both Win XP and 7 with both release and developer version installed and never had any problems.

Comment: Older versions can only be installed by standalone installer, which you can find here: http://qgis.org/downloads/. I have 1.7.4, 1.8.0 (both standalone) and master (Osgeo4w) running on my computer. Only disadvantage are some plugins which work only on specific versions. Programms are installed separately, but for plugins they take the same folder. You have to uninstall those plugins, or get an error each time qgis starts.