# Plugin causes QGIS to crash on startup

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, mac

I get the message "the plugin will be disabled because it crashed QGIS during last startup." Which plugin? None is identified. I'm a bit of a rookie so not sure where to look to solve this.
Running on a Mac with Mountain Lion, using QGIS Essen 2.14[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the plugin **processing**.

QGIS 2.14 comes with a mechanism that deactivates plugins if they did not successfully load on QGIS startup.

This points out a potential problem in the plugin. Save your work and try to re-enable the plugin and if it fails to load again, file an issue (for the plugin, not for QGIS).

---

**In its first version (2.14.0) there is a problem** with this mechanism that doesn't recover the warning once the problem has been fixed.

To disable the warning open the python console, paste the following snippet and press enter.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSettings
QSettings().remove('/PythonPlugins/watchDog/processing')
```

Starting from QGIS 2.14.1 and 2.16, there is no longer a reason to use the python console. If the plugin could be loaded manually from the plugin manager the warning will be turned off (since this means that the plugin is actually safe to load).

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Plugin-processing-problem-tp5256936p5256980.html

Answer (score 3):

It's the **processing** plugin.

It caught me out at first glance too, because *processing* is something that you think might be happening to any plugin as it loads.

Comment: Thanks for this. Cannot see how to fix it though. Uninstalled and reinstalled - same thing again.

Comment: Well GIS.SE is meant to be a single question and answer site, so I answered the question _which plugin_, not the supplementary how to fix it question.  You should really post a second question about that issue.  But now you know which plugin you can look at the error messages you get when you attempt to reinstall it.  Also take a look on the web to see if the issue has been reported elsewhere, for example: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175636/qgis-updating-processing-plugin might be useful

Comment: Again. Thanks for your help. No joy, however, as I get this: Installed version: 2.12.99. Available version: 2.12.2 and downgrading doesn't seem to do anything. I'll live with it.

Comment: still it might be worth you posing a second question, because it may highlight a problem and some QGIS dev might be able to supply a fix...  it appears that there are a few issues with this plugin: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Plugin-processing-problem-td5256936.html

Answer (score 2):

On a Mac running MacOS 10.11.4 (El Capitan) this worked for me:

Download and install the latest QGIS. (Version 2.14.2 was posted to the download site around May 7, 2016.)

Launch the app and go to Plugins > Manage and install > Installed, then look in the list of plugins for one called "Processing" and check the box. Restart.

Answer (score 0):

99% is that you upgraded qgis having an old installed version of Processing.
Processing plugin is a core plugin and it's always availabe as core plugin, but it can be also installed via plugin manager (so intalled in $HOME/.qgis2/python/plugins/) so upgrade current core version.

try to:
1) de install processing plugin (if this is allowed means you have an installed version in $HOME/.qgis2/python/plugins/)
2) rerun qgis