# QGIS - couldn't load plugin "processing" - cannot import "bytes"

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing

I just tried to update QGIS, and now get two errors.

This when I open the app

[image]

And this when I try to access the processing plugin.

```
couldn't load plugin 'processing' 
    
ImportError: cannot import name 'BYTES' from 'psycopg2._psycopg' (C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd) 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 312, in loadPlugin
    __import__(packageName)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\__init__.py", line 25, in 
    from processing.tools.general import *              # NOQA
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\general.py", line 32, in 
    from processing.core.Processing import Processing
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\core\Processing.py", line 54, in 
    from processing.algs.qgis.QgisAlgorithmProvider import QgisAlgorithmProvider  # NOQA
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\QgisAlgorithmProvider.py", line 66, in 
    from .FieldsCalculator import FieldsCalculator
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\FieldsCalculator.py", line 42, in 
    from .ui.FieldsCalculatorDialog import FieldsCalculatorDialog
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\algs\qgis\ui\FieldsCalculatorDialog.py", line 50, in 
    from processing.gui.PostgisTableSelector import PostgisTableSelector
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\gui\PostgisTableSelector.py", line 32, in 
    from processing.tools.postgis import GeoDB
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing\tools\postgis.py", line 24, in 
    import psycopg2
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 68, in 
    from psycopg2 import extensions as _ext
  File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
    mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\extensions.py", line 37, in 
    from psycopg2._psycopg import (                             # noqa
ImportError: cannot import name 'BYTES' from 'psycopg2._psycopg' (C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\_psycopg.cp37-win_amd64.pyd)


Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 3.8.3-Zanzibar Zanzibar, 685d8b15d2 

Python Path:
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/stuar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
C:/Users/stuar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins
C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python37.zip
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\DLLs
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:/Users/stuar/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the processing plugin, in my experience sometimes the path gets messed up. You could try to simply uninstall/reinstall the processing plugin using the plugin manager.

Another thread you could reference seems to explain that this happens commonly when running 2 versions of QGIS:
[Missing Processing Tools in Vector Menu of QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/202111/missing-processing-tools-in-vector-menu-of-qgis)

Comment: Processing is a core plugin so I can't uninstall. The problem feels like its coming from the path / having 2 versions of QGIS.

Comment: This is a somewhat dated thread but shows you the path of the processing plugin: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/175636/qgis-updating-processing-plugin